# Get image deletion in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a contenteditable div. I have img tag inside the div. Is there a way to identify if the img tag is deleted??

```
<div contenteditable id="note">
  <img src="images/xyz.jpg" />
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>

 $('#note').keyup(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 8) {
            //Identify whether image was deleted??
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#note').keyup(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 8) {
          console.log($(this).find('img').length);
          // if 0, this will return false
      }
 });
```